# write terminal output to file while keeping new lines

Tags: bash, echo, printf

when I call `env` to see the environment variables it shows nicely with new lines:

```
$ env
SHELL=/bin/sh    
EDITOR=vi
PWD=/home/user
...
```

but when I want to store this to a file the new lines get discarded:

```
$ echo $(env) > root.env
SHELL=/bin/sh EDITOR=vi PWD=/home/user ...
```

What goes wrong? how can I store the `env` output with each item on a line?

Comment: Try `env > root.env`.  No need to use a subshell.

Comment: @Stewart Well thanks that worked, but why echo fails then?

Comment: Typing it in an answer.  But it's because the subshell returns line-by-line.  Not just a single string of text containing newlines.

Comment: It's the same word-splitting issue as [Why does echo of awk in a bash script remove line breaks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306824/why-does-echo-of-awk-in-a-bash-script-remove-line-breaks)

Comment: and also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting. But there's seldom, if ever a need to do `echo $(...)`, the `echo` and the command substitution just undo each other.

Comment: [What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)`?](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)